# How to tell if an apply_async function has started or if it's still in the queue with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using python's multiprocessing.Pool and apply_async to call a bunch of functions.

How can I tell whether a function has started processing by a member of the pool or whether it is sitting in a queue?

For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def func(t):
    #take some time processing
    print 'func({}) started'.format(t)
    time.sleep(t)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

results = [pool.apply_async(func, [t]) for t in [100]*50] #adds 50 func calls to the queue
```

For each `AsyncResult` in `results` you can call `ready()` or `get(0)` to see if the func finished running. But how do you find out whether the func  *started* but hasn't finished yet?

i.e. for a given AsyncResult object (i.e. a given element of results) is there a way to see whether the function has been called or if it's sitting in the pool's queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove completed jobs from results list

```
    results = [r for r in results if not r.ready()]
```

Number of processes pending is length of results list:

```
    pending = len(results)
```

And number pending but not started is total pending - pool_size

```
    not_started = pending - pool_size
```

pool_size will be multiprocessing.cpu_count() if Pool is created with default argument as you did

**UPDATE**:
After initially misunderstanding the question, here's a way to do what OP was asking about.

I suspect this functionality could be added to the Pool class without too much trouble because AsyncResult is implemented by Pool with a Queue.  That queue could also be used internally to indicate whether started or not.

But here's a way to implement using Pool and Pipe.  NOTE: this doesn't work in Python 2.x -- not sure why.  Tested in Python 3.8.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

def worker_function(pipe):
    pipe.send('started')
    print('[{}] started pipe={}'.format(os.getpid(), pipe))
    time.sleep(3)
    pipe.close()

def test():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    print('[{}] pool={}'.format(os.getpid(), pool))

    workers = []

    for x in range(1, 4):
        parent, child = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        pool.apply_async(worker_function, (child,))
        worker = {'name': 'worker{}'.format(x), 'pipe': parent, 'started': False}
        workers.append(worker)

    pool.close()

    while True:
        for worker in workers:
            if worker.get('started'):
                continue
            pipe = worker.get('pipe')
            if pipe.poll(0.1):
                message = pipe.recv()
                print('[{}] {} says {}'.format(os.getpid(), worker.get('name'), message))
                worker['started'] = True
                pipe.close()
        count_in_queue = len(workers)
        for worker in workers:
            if worker.get('started'):
                count_in_queue -= 1
        print('[{}] count_in_queue = {}'.format(os.getpid(), count_in_queue))
        if not count_in_queue:
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)

    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: This gets the total number of pending jobs. But I want to know if `results[i]` is currently running (for any `i`) or if it's sitting in the queue waiting to run.

Comment: @Alex right, I misunderstood the question.  I've updated with some code that will keep track of which are started and which are in Pool queue